# Copying <tbody> text using zclip when running as a file

Tags: jquery, zclip

I'm trying to copy the text from the body of a html table using zclip. Should be a simple thing to do (I can copy a paragraph's text, for example, but not a table body's text). Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Here's the fiddle code:

http://jsfiddle.net/LNd6p/5/

```
<button id="copy-description">Copy table data</button>
&nbsp;
<table>
    <thead><tr><th>Q1</th><th>Q2</th><th>Q3</th></tr></thad>
        <tbody id="surveyResultsTable"><tr><td>Blah1</td><td>Blah2</td><td>Blah3</td>  </tr></tbody>
    </table>|
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //copy the contents of surveyResultTable
    $('#copy-description').click(function(){
        $('#copy-description').zclip({
            path:'http://zeroclipboard.googlecode.com/svn-history/r10/trunk/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy:function(){return $('#surveyResultsTable').text();}
        });
    });
});
```

**Edit**
Not sure why it's not working locally. I'm trying to run it as a file (that is, not served through a localhost webserver).

Here's the exact code from the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html lang="en"><head><script type="text/javascript" src="head.load.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
  <button id="copy-description">Copy table data</button>
  &nbsp;
  <table>
    <thead><tr><th>Q1</th><th>Q2</th><th>Q3</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody id="surveyResultsTable"><tr><td>Blah1;</td><td>Blah2;</td><td>Blah3;</td></tr></tbody>
  </table>
<script type="text/javascript">head.load("jquery-2.1.1.min.js", "jquery.zclip.min.js", "test.js");</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's test.js

```
$('#copy-description').zclip({
  path:'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
  copy:function(){return $('#surveyResultsTable').text();}
});
```

Here's the working fiddle with the same code (html head stuff stripped). http://jsfiddle.net/LNd6p/8/ Eventually, I'll have to run this as a file on a tablet not connected to the internet, so remotely serving it isn't an option. I'm running Firefox 32.
Firebug isn't giving any javascript errors. The swf file is loading (I'm not even trying to serve that locally at the moment), but clicking it doesn't do anything. I'm running this as a file, with `file:///D:/projets/test.html` in the address bar of the browser. It's not working in IE either - haven't got any webkit browsers to test; my intention was to run this in Firefox anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call `zclip` on the `click` event, but `zclip` library is using flash for copy text.. so dependent flash resource can't load instantly, no need click event, you should use only  `<selector>` in `zclip` function see below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//copy the contents of surveyResultTable
    $('#copy-description').zclip({
       path:'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
       copy:function(){
          return $('#surveyResultsTable').text();
       }
    });
})
```

PS: `zlip` swf file path was wrong in your fiddle code,

## DEMO

Comment: Well this is baffling. Your fiddle works fine (thanks!) when it's on the jsfille server, but not locally despite copy-pasting the same code. I'm doing this on firefox so it shouldn't have the "nothing works locally" webkit problems. Give me a little while to look into this.

Comment: what is error showing on local server.. did check in `firebug`??

Comment: No firebug errors. I've even inspected the html inside the fiddle iframe; it's the same as in the file after rendering. I've updated the original question with the actual code from the files I'm using. They work in jsfiddle, but not as files.

Comment: check you local server code.. `zclip` is also stop working.. if section container is resizing after page loading.. please make sure in you code.

Comment: I have no server code. I'm running this as a file, with `file:///D:/projets/test.html` in the address bar of the browser.

Comment: Everything I read about this says that Adobe Flash player has an internal restriction about data collection when running as a file, and that I therefore can't expect zclip to work unless I serve it online. I'm going to rethink how I'm going to approach the problem more generally, and accept Girish's original answer as correct, with thanks.